# Поиск одинаковых строк в 2-х текстовых файлах

Tags: bat

Какой командой можно осуществить поиск одинаковых строк в 2-х текстовых файлах,
и если такие найдутся создать и записать их в новый файл.
Например 1.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
```

2.txt:

```
4
5
6
7
```

После выполнения команды создастся файл result.txt:
4

Comment: если незнаешь, не пиши ерунды

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, такая утилита есть в комплекте Windows:

```
findstr /g:1.txt 2.txt>result.txt
```

Comment: благодарю, очень помог